# Agrupar array de emails pelo domínio de cada email em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, array, objetos

Tenho um array de emails:

```
emails = [
  "name1@domain1.com",
  "name2@domain1.com",
  "name1@domain2.com",
  "name2@domaind2.com"
]
```

Estou usando expressões regulares para analisar os domínios, e minha intenção é criar um JSON com a seguinte estrutura:

```
json = {
  "@domain1.com": ["name1", ..., "nameN"],
  ...
  "@domain2.com": ["name1", ..., "nameN"]
}
```

Estou iterando sobre cada email da array *emails*, e ao obter o domínio, quero checar se este já existe no JSON. Se sim, acrescentar o `name` no array deste domínio e, se não, criar um novo domínio e acrescentar o `name`.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `reduce` para iterar sobre o `array` e montar o objeto com os grupos:

```js
const emails = [
  "name1@domain1.com",
  "name2@domain1.com",
  "name1@domain2.com",
  "name2@domaind2.com"
];

const grupos = emails.reduce((acumulador, email) => {
  const [nome, dominio] = email.split('@');
  const grupo = acumulador[`@${dominio}`] ?? [];
  acumulador[`@${dominio}`] = [...grupo, nome];
  return acumulador;
}, {});

console.log(grupos);
```

---

> [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
>
> O método `reduce()` executa uma função `reducer` (provida por você) para cada membro do array, resultando num único valor de retorno.
>
> **Exemplo:**
>
> ```js
> const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
> const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;
>
> // 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
> // expected output: 10
>
> // 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
> console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
> // expected output: 15
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Se fosse só agrupar poderia usar um `reduce` mas como precisa gerar um objeto com uma estrutura nova, pensei em percorrer os itens e adicionar a um novo elemento, agrupando por domínio:

```js
var emails = ["name1@domain1.com",
"name2@domain1.com",
"name3@domain2.com",
"name4@domaind2.com"];


var emailAgrupado = {};

emails.forEach(email => {
   // aqui pode usar um regex
   var nome   = email.substring(0, email.lastIndexOf('@'));
   var domain = email.substring(email.lastIndexOf('@'));
    
   // verifica se já existe um elemento com o dominio como chave, senão cria
   if (!emailAgrupado[domain]) {
        emailAgrupado[domain] = [];
    }
    
    // adiciona o nome ao dominio
    emailAgrupado[domain].push(nome);

});

console.log(emailAgrupado);
```

Answer (score 5):

Uma opção é iterar sobre cada elemento do array original, dividir o elemento (que é uma string) pelo caractere `@` e ir inserindo em um dicionário de arrays conforme o domínio. Note que não é nem necessário utilizar expressões regulares para dividir cada e-mail.

A lógica para a criação desse dicionário é simples:

- Se o domínio em questão ainda não tiver sido registrado, atribui-se à ele um novo array, preenchido com o primeiro elemento já registrado.
- Caso contrário (inferindo-se que o domínio já foi registrado e já depreende um array), insere-se o e-mail na lista já existente.

Essa é uma técnica muito comum. Se quiser alguns outros exemplos parecidos, veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+code%3A%22const+map%22).

```js
function groupByDomain(emailList) {
  const map = {};
  
  for (const email of emailList) {
    // Dividimos o e-mail pelo caractere `@`:
    const [user, domain] = email.split('@');
    const atDomain = '@' + domain;
    
    if (!map[atDomain]) {
      // Caso nenhum e-mail do domínio atual já tiver sido registrado,
      // inserimos um array com o e-mail atual já preenchido.
      map[atDomain] = [user];
    } else {
      // Se o domínio atual já tiver sido registrado, simplesmente
      // adiciona-se um novo e-mail à lista.
      map[atDomain].push(user);
    }
  }
  
  return map;
}

console.log(
  groupByDomain([
    'name1@domain1.com',
    'name2@domain1.com',
    'name3@domain2.com',
    'name4@domaind2.com',
  ])
);
```

E, conforme sugerido pela [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/494770/69296), daria para se fazer com `reduce` também. A lógica é a mesma — veja como ficaria:

```js
function groupByDomain(emailList) {
  return emailList.reduce((map, email) => {
    const [user, domain] = email.split('@');
    const atDomain = '@' + domain;

    if (!map[atDomain]) {
      map[atDomain] = [user];
    } else {
      map[atDomain].push(user);
    }

    return map;
  }, {});
}

console.log(
  groupByDomain([
    'name1@domain1.com',
    'name2@domain1.com',
    'name3@domain2.com',
    'name4@domaind2.com'
  ])
);
```

Comment: +1 Sem benchmark dessa vez? :)

Comment: @CmteCardeal, hoje não; até porque as soluções apresentadas parecem ter a mesma complexidade. Desconsiderando o `substring` da outra resposta e o `split` da minha, O(n). :-)